# In node.js how to extract uid from returned facebook providerData json array?

Tags: javascript, json

I've got my users signing in with facebook and that gets stored in firebase auth. In index.js i've got an onCreate function that stores some facebook related data in firestore.

When i log to cloud functions console event.data.providerData I get this:

```
[ { displayName: 'xxxx xxxxx',
    photoURL: 'https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/p100x100/xxxxxxxxx_439xxx336xxxxxx.jpg?oh=bcxxxxxxxxxxx431ce&oe=xxxx4xxx3',
    providerId: 'facebook.com',
    uid: 'xxxxx725xxxxxx80' } ]
```

In my index.js file i've set this as

```
const providerData = event.data.providerData;
```

This always confuses me and i've read about it a lot.

These are my questions:

1. Is this a javascript object? Or a JSON object? Or a JSON array?
2. Does this need to be parsed? eg. JSON.parse(event.data.providerData)? What is JSON.parse actually doing?

To get access to the uid I have tried:

```
providerData[3]
providerData.uid
providerData["uid"]
providerData['uid']
JSON.parse(providerData) - and then all the above again

var obj = JSON.parse(providerData);
console.log( obj.uid );
```

I know there are plenty of posts out there re: similar topics and I think i've read a lot of them.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an array containing a JSON object at index `0`.

The javascript interpreter is automatically parsing Valid JSON as a Javascript object.

Knowing that, you can now access directly the properties of your object like this:

```
providerData[0].displayName
providerData[0].photoURL
providerData[0].providerId
providerData[0].uid // <-- Your use case
```

Comment: Thanks. That all makes sense now. Cheers